# (For Christian Moral Theologians) What is the third moral principle that forbids gender change?

Tags: ethics, christianity

Shortly after the beginning, Cain kills Abel. (Genesis 4:8) In light of this, God sees it fit to create a new moral rule for all of humanity.

1. "Do unto others as you would have them do unto you." (Luke 6:31)

Many thousands of years later, a Prussian philosopher by the name of Immanuel Kant realized that this is not enough. He realized that people would misinterpret this rule to mean that as long as I am not directly affecting others, I can do as I please (non-aggression principle). So in order to remove irrational, ungeneralizable behavior such as drug usage, Immanuel Kant created an addendum to God's rule.

1. "Do unto others as you would have them do unto you." (Luke 6:31)
2. "Treat yourself as you would have others treat themselves."

Now let's suppose that some new alien technology falls from the sky that makes complete and perfect biological sex change possible: you step into the portal, and you emerge a perfect, biologically-complete version of the opposite sex. Most Christian theologians would conclude that you are forbidden from using such technology.

So what's the third rule that God and Immanuel Kant missed?

The gender-changing alien technology doesn't violate Rule #1 (nobody is harmed, unless you consider any kind of self-change to be "harm") and it doesn't violate Rule #2 (society would be a lot more fluid, but ultimately, the human race could continue to procreate if e.g. a gay man chose to turn into a woman, so it's not self-destructive in the way ununiversalizable behavior like drug usage would be).

So there must be a third undiscovered rule of morality that Jesus and everybody else missed. What is that rule?

Comment: But the question is about Christian theologians or about moral? IMO there is no ethical principle forbidding gender change.

Comment: It feels like this very much a Christianity.se question. I get that the ethical nature of Christian pronouncements would have philosophical import, but I don’t think it carries independent philosophical weight.

Comment: Of course, that stack exchange site thinks it is inappropriate to them, but perhaps all that means is that Christianity is hostile to its own analysis.

Comment: IMO it is not an "ethical" rule: it depends on Christian anthropology and philosophical views about human nature: God defined the "laws of nature", human beings included, and these laws are immutable. Compare with Simone De Beauvoir's famous dictum in Book II of *The Second Sex* (1949): "One is not born, but rather becomes, woman." This statement derives from Jean-Paul Sartre's existential philosophy:  the existence precedes essence. This theory is clearly at odds with Aristotelian and Thomist ontology.

Comment: Between Genesis and Kant there was St. Thomas and his conception of natural law. The rule, as described by [Catholic Encyclopedia](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09076a.htm), "*is found in our nature itself. Those actions which conform with its tendencies, lead to our destined end, and are thereby constituted right and morally good; those at variance with our nature are wrong and immoral.*" Sex change is, presumably, "unnatural" and against God's "destined end", or so its detractors would hold (many do today). Love thy God above all else, thyself or neighbor, was Jesus's first commandment.

Comment: "Most Christian theologians would conclude that you are forbidden from using such technology." Would they? That seems like something that you should cite.

Comment: The question can likely be rephrased into one that fits christianity.se . Just drop the assumptions in the question

Comment: Title should likely be about sex change, not gender change

Comment: There is not just one Christianity, and not just one version of the bible. In biblical times, sex change was not a relevant topic (other than maybe castration of male slaves), so it won't directly mention it. As such theology is required, not philosophy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is really appropriate for the group, but one commenter says that the christianity.se group doesn't think it's appropriate for them, so I'll try to answer in a philosophical manner, by analyzing Christian moral teaching objectively.

First, Christian moral teaching is not summed up in "do to others as you would have them do to you". That is just one of a long list of aphorisms that Jesus gave. In fact, the Golden Rule is not even unique to Christianity but predates Christianity (more precisely, the negative form "do not do to others what you would not want others to do to you" predates Christianity).

However, Jesus did give a principle that could be called the core of Christian moral thought in this passage from Mathew 22:

> 36 “Teacher, which is the greatest commandment in the Law?”
>
> 37 Jesus replied: “‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and
> with all your soul and with all your mind.’ 38 This is the first and
> greatest commandment. 39 And the second is like it: ‘Love your
> neighbor as yourself.’ 40 All the Law and the Prophets hang on these
> two commandments.”

As you can see, this is a more oblique approach to morality. It doesn't give you a directly applicable formula like "do unto others"; instead, it gives some oblique commands from which moral principles can be derived. Note that there are three commands here: love God, love your neighbor, and love yourself.

Naturally, what moral principles someone derives from these three commands will depend to some extent on additional things that that they believe, but in deciding how to apply these commands, you have to use the beliefs of people who obey all three commands. The beliefs of people who reject any of them are not relevant.

One of the additional things that Christians believe is that the roles of man and woman are sacred and ordained by God. Because of this, they would generally approach the idea of changing your sex differently from the idea of changing your hair color, height, or breast size (although many traditional Christians are opposed to optional cometic surgery as well).

Given this background, what would a traditional Christian say about sex change? Most likely, the following:

(1) If you love God, then you will accept the role he has given in you in the body he has given you.

(2) If you love your neighbor, then you will not want to cause consternation, strife and chaos by making dramatic society-wide changes to personal relationships, and you will not want to bring grief to the people who love you.

(3) If you love yourself, you will not want to make a fundamental change to what you are.

Comment: This is the best philosophical answer I've ever read on this site. Thank you. Everything is logical and sound, except for #3. I do not think it is proven that self-change logically implies self-hatred. There should be a field in philosophy on the subject of self-changing or self-modification called autoplastology.

Comment: @Lisramic, thank you for the kind words. You are correct, of course, that just wanting to change things about yourself doesn't necessarily mean that you don't love yourself. You could, for example just want to see what it's like being different. In fact, all three of the claims stand in need of further justification.

Comment: @HolyKnowledge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Cyborg_Manifesto There's: Leviticus 19:28 “You shall not make gashes in your flesh for the dead, or incise any marks on yourselves.” Though many Christians do get tattoos, including memorial ones. Adam seems to have been created non-gendered or both-gendered, before the creation of Eve, though.

Comment: @CriglCragl "Adam seems to have been created non-gendered or both-gendered, before the creation of Eve, though." <- That's the traditional Jewish reading of "male and female created He them".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Conifold, natural law is one of the typical justifications. A couple of things to note:

(a): Most proponents of natural law today would endorse that natural law (NL) is "independent" of Chrisitianity. NL is neither implied by nor implies Chrisitianity, and in particular, it admits of no faith to accept- or no faith beyond that of accepting any philosophical position.

(b): In practice, one needs to have some notion of teleology built into their metaphysics. Since teleology went out of favor since the Enlightment, not too many people beside (catholics?) defend the view anymore.

(c): The particular problem is the mutiliation of the body for purposes that violate the natural ends of those body parts. In particular, a NL proponent will say that a sex change accomplished via surgery is directly counter to the natural end of reproduction via those parts. The analogy is the same as chopping off ones own fingers, directly counter to natural function of the hand. Actually in your example, no surgery is done(?), so perhaps the NL people will say this is ok.

(d): I don't claim to be current with NL, so please see a modern day proponent, say Pruss, or any of the neo-Thomists, for a better engagement.

(e): the other reason is that many Christians no doubt accept some form of gender essentialism. Unfortunately, I cant point you to many sources here, but it may be the case that many NL proponents are also proponents of this view, so it should be ok.

Comment: A great answer in general, but I don't think you will find anyone who is critical of gender ideology who accepts any form of "gender essentialism". Instead, they would deny that gender (as understood in gender ideology) exists at all. It is not a real (or even a coherent) property, and so it is not an essential property. There is only sex, and sex is binary. Nor would they necessarily be essentialist with respect to sex. Just because a property is an accident doesn't mean that it can be changed at a whim.